# Why Colorbox doesn't work on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm using [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) in my app. What I'm looking for is, on page load hide div (.box) and when I click on the link, it opens (div.box) and shows it's title (My Box) and style.

```
<div class="click" href="link">Click here!</div>

<div class="box" style="width:700; height:800;" title="My Box">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Here is what i have tried.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.click').click(function () {

            open_colorbox(newWidth, newHeight, newTitle);
      });

    function open_colorbox(c_width, c_height, c_title) {
     var options = {
       width: c_width,
       height: c_height,
       title: c_title,
       overlayClose: false
     };
     $.colorbox(options);
    }
  });
  </script>
```

The above solution doesn't work. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE 1:**

Based on the below comments and answer(s) I only use one line to open colorbox, but still not working!!!

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.click').click(function () {
       $(".box").colorbox({ open: true });
     });
  });
</script>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to @Franklin. His solution is the correct one. Here is an example of how simple Colorbox can be done. http://codepen.io/egyamado/pen/Jnxvi

Comment: Have you included all the correct files? Have you checked firebug/developer tools for errors?

Comment: you haven't defined these variables: `newWidth, newHeight, newTitle`

Comment: @Pete Thanks for sharp eyes. I don;t know how I didn't notice that. I have updated my code but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your click function, can't you just do...

Try adding #id of the div

```
    $(".box").colorbox({href:"#id", inline:true});
```

Or

```
$("a.click").colorbox({href:"#id", inline:true});
```

Comment: I tried your solution which it works and show the Colorbox modal, but its empty, it didn't show the div 'box'. When I check the source code for 'div#cboxWrapper' it was empty.

Comment: Still not working with me. Does 'href' still work weather I'm clicking on 'a' tag or not?

Comment: Did you try both methods in my answer?

Comment: When i try the second solution, it loads the page with colorbox empty then everything disappears.

Comment: Try adding width:"700px"

Comment: Ok I updated my answer, can't pass div without inline:true, my mistake. Replace 'open' with 'inline'